# Windows XP static route to LAN, default route to loopback or non-existent interface

Tags: networking, windows-xp, routing

I have an XP standalone workstation that I want to really lock down so it can't get online outside of the LAN, even if the user knows a site's IP address. My LAN has addresses of 10.10.0.0/16 and 166.100.100.0/24.

```
route add 10.10.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.10.8.1 metric 1 if 2
```

works, as does

```
route add 166.100.100.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.10.8.1 metric 1 if 2
```

to access the Mac segment. I want to have all other IPs, i.e. the default route 0.0.0.0, go to a non-existent interface or the loopback address, if that's possible. The following commands all fail.

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 metric 1 if 1
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 metric 1
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 if 1
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1
```

Is it possible to create a fake interface to route traffic through?

Comment: Why not just remove the default route all together?

Comment: I can't see how to persistently delete the default route. My workaround was to make a scheduled task that deletes it on startup. If no one else can show how to do that, propose your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: How is the default route getting there in the first place?  Via dhcp?

Comment: It's created by the OS on startup. With multiple NICs, you can assign one to host/be the default route. At least, that's the case with Linux. I was looking for another NIC to install and not hook up a network cable. I would then be able to assign the default route to the NIC with no cable attached.

Comment: You can assign one to be the default route, but why do you want to?  Edit the tcpv4 properties in the network settings for each of the nics and remove the default gateway.

Comment: I don't see any options for changing or removing the default gateway. I got around this by using the document here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/839013 to create a "virtual" interface, then assigned that as the default route's interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a default gateway, the best option is to remove it from the interface configuration.

Go to the interface properties and choose TCPv4 properties.

If this is set to "obtain an ip address automatically" then DHCP is setting the IP address, and defining the default gateway.  In which case, the simplest solution is to use a static address.

[image]